# How do I set a percentage chance

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a bot and I want to add wheel of fortune.

```js
bot.on('message', async message => {
    if(message.content.startsWith('+wheel')) {
        let userbal = db.fetch(`money_${message.author.id}`)
        let type = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
        let types = ["basic", "classic", "premium"];
        if(!type) return message.reply('...');
        if(!type === types.some(type => message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ") === type)) return message.reply('...');
        if(type === 'basic') {
            let cost = 100
            //
            const wheel = require('./wheel.json');
            const wheels = [wheel.s1, wheel.s2, wheel.s3, wheel.s4, wheel.s5, wheel.s6, wheel.s7, wheel.s8];
            var slot = Math.floor(Math.random() * wheels.length);
            //
            if(userbal < cost) return message.reply('...');
            db.subtract(`money_${message.author.id}`, cost);
            message.channel.send('...');
            if(wheels[slot] === wheel.s1) {
                message.channel.send('...')
                db.push(message.author.id, "...")
            }
}}});
```

But here all the options have the equal chances. How can I make it so that for example `wheels.s1` has a 70% chance, `wheels.s2` 30%, `wheels.s3` 45% and so on?

Comment: This isn't the right forum for this question. Stackoverflow isn't about asking people to write code for you or asking people how to code. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and focus on the search and research portion.

Comment: none of this code makes a lot of sense. I would start over.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute easiest method: simply repeat each element in the list as many times as you'd like their relative probabilities to be. (If you want, they can all sum up to, say, 100 or 1000, to make thinking about their probabilities easier.)

```
function pushTimes(list, item, times) {
  for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    list.push(item);
  }
}

const wheel = require("./wheel.json");
const wheels = [];
pushTimes(wheels, wheel.s1, 70);
pushTimes(wheels, wheel.s2, 30);
pushTimes(wheels, wheel.s3, 45);
// ... etc ...
var slot = Math.floor(Math.random() * wheels.length);
```

It's not as elegant as methods involving actual numbers, but will work fine unless you'll have many hundreds of items. The elegant, lighter method would be a list with each item, its probability (or weight), and you'd choose a number between 0 and the sum of those probabilities, then choose an item based on that number.

Comment: hard to tell what the OP is asking, but this is not going to work unless you end up with exactly 100 items, which doesn't not appear to be the case.

Comment: @Rick - incorrect :) As I said, it doesn't have to be 100 items. It can be 1000, 10000... heck, for chances of 20%/40%/40%, you can do with a list of [a, b, b, c, c]. :)

Comment: right your solution works well. I'm just saying if the OP truly wants "70% chance" than he needs to make sure the items add up to exactly 100. but it's unclear from reading the OP what he truly wants because he gives percentages that add up to more than 100%. so maybe he will be happy with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to repeat the elements of an array.
like if you want to double the chances of s1, then the array will look like

`const wheels = [wheel.s1, wheel.s1, wheel.s2, wheel.s3, wheel.s4, wheel.s5, wheel.s6, wheel.s7, wheel.s8];`

Other approach is to use a weighted array. You can give range between [0, 1] to each element. For example,

`weight= [0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1]`
Here we have 3 times chances of getting s1.